# powershell character encoding from System.Net.WebClient

Tags: windows, encoding, powershell

I am running the following command:

```
([xml](new-object net.webclient).DownloadString(
"http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/rss.aspx"
)).rss.channel.item | format-table title,link
```

The output for one of the RSS items contains this weird text:

```
You Donâ€™t Have to Be An Administrator to Run Remote PowerShell Commands
```

So, the question is:

- Why the mix up in characters? What happened to the apostrophe? Why is the output rendered as `Donâ€™t` when it should just render as `Don't`?
- How would I get the correct character in the PowerShell standard output?

Comment: this shows an important aspect of powershell .Net interaction.
I usually program in .Net and failed to view this as a .Net setting to be made.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set the encoding property of the webclient:

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
([xml]$wc.DownloadString( "http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/rss.aspx" )).rss.channel.item | format-table title,link
```