# Powershell using gzip for downloading by WebClient and Downloadstring()

Tags: powershell, gzip, webclient, downloadstring

Is it possible to make a `downloadstring()` and using `gzip-compression`, if the server is accepting this?

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other")

$qc = $wc.Downloadstring($url)
```

Does anyone know the correct `Headers.Add` or what do we have to add?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019251/powershell-character-problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470474/powershell-httpwebrequest-get-method-cookiecontainer-problem

Comment: Could you try it and if it fails add some error logging?

Comment: If we add $wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate") we will get lots of Timeout - Errors.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```powershell
$url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers.Add([System.Net.HttpRequestHeader]::AcceptEncoding, "gzip")
$wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other")
$qc = $wc.Downloadstring($url)
```

Alternatively you can try and use `DownloadFile` method to see if this yields an expected result:

```powershell
$wc.DownloadFile($url, "c:\temp\dump.txt" )
```

If there are errors then update your question to include them.

Comment: This works perfekctly and downloads the Content as an gzip - String (or file with DownloadFile() ).

Do you also know the way to decompress the $qc - variable as an normal "string"?

Comment: Most likely you will have to use .Net GzipStream class but it's best if you post it as a separate question.